# Jqgrid not displaying after hosting in iss

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, jqgrid

i have created a report form using jqgrid 4.7 in asp.net web form
in asp.net 4.0.

it works fine in local visual studio but not working  after hoisting In IIS
page displaying Empty.

i have posted my script below,
please suggest me some solutions.

*-------here my code---- do needfull, thanx in advance.*

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
        serializeEditData: function (postData) {
            var postdata = { 'data': postData };
            return JSON.stringify(postdata);;
        }
     });
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.del, {
        ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
        onclickSubmit: function (eparams) {
            var retarr = {};
            var sr = jQuery("#datagrid").getGridParam('selrow');
            rowdata = jQuery("#datagrid").getRowData(sr);
            retarr = { PID: rowdata.PID };
            return retarr;
        },
        serializeDelData: function (data) {
            var postData = { 'data': data };
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        }
    });

    filters = {
               "groupOp": "AND", "rules": [{ "field": "id", "op": "gt", "data": "1" },
               { "field": "name", "op": "bw", "data": "Client" }]
            }

    $("#datagrid").jqGrid({
        url: 'MIS.aspx/GetMIS',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
        serializeGridData: function (postData) {
            if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
        },
        jsonReader: { root: "d.rows", page: "d.page", total: "d.total", records: "d.records", cell: "cell", id: "0", /* index of the column with the PK in it userdata: "userdata",*/ repeatitems: false },
        colNames:['Customer Name', 'Handling Branch', 'Handler Name', 'Transaction Origin', 'Last Action', 'Last Action Date', 'Reason', 'EnquiryNo', 'QuoteRefNo',
                    'SaleorderNo', 'Enquiry Created By', 'Enquiry Created Date', 'Assigned Date', 'Enquiry Mode', 'Enquiry Reference', 'Quote Submitted For Approval',
                    'Manager', 'Quote Approved Date', 'Quote Sent Date', 'Quote Value', 'PurchaseOrder Value ', 'PurchaseOrder No', 'PurchaseOrder Date', 'Reference', 'PO Type', 'SalesOpportunity',
                 ],
        colModel: [       
                   {      
                    name: 'CustomerName', index: 'CustomerName',      
                    searchoptions: {sopt: ['eq', 'cn']}, searchrules: { "required": true }, width: 150, sortable: true, sorttype: 'text'
                   },
                   { name: 'HandlerBranch', index: 'HandlerBranch', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, width: 100, searchrules: { "required": true }, sorttype:         'text' },
                   { name: 'HandlerName', index: 'HandlerName', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, width: 100, searchrules: { "required": true }, sorttype: 'text' },
                   { name: 'TransactionOrigin', index: 'TransactionOrigin', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, width: 100, searchrules: { "required": true },        sorttype: 'text' },
                   { name: 'LastAction', index: 'LastAction',width: 150, stype: "select",
                           searchoptions: {
                                value: getStatus(), sopt: ['cn']
                            }, sorttype: 'text'
                   },
                   { name: 'LastActionDate', index: 'LastActionDate', width: 100,sorttype:'date',
                           searchoptions: {
                                sopt: ['eq','ge', 'le'],
                                dataInit: function (element) {
                                    $(element).datepicker({
                                        id: 'ActionDate_datePicker',
                                        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',                                    
                                        showOn: 'focus'
                                    });
                                }
                            },
                            sortable: true, width: 100, searchrules: { "required": true }
                   },
                   { name: 'Reason', index: 'Reason', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, searchrules: { "required": true }, width: 100, sorttype: 'text' },
                   { name: 'EnquiryNo', index: 'EnquiryNo', width: 100, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, searchrules: { "required": true }, sorttype: 'text' },
                   { name: 'QuoteRefNo', index: 'QuoteRefNo', width: 100, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, searchrules: { "required": true }, sorttype: 'text' },
                   { name: 'SaleOrderNo', index: 'SaleOrderNo', width: 100, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, searchrules: { "required": true }, sorttype: 'text' },
                   { name: 'EnquiryCreatedBy', index: 'EnquiryCreatedBy', width: 100, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, searchrules: { "required": true }, sorttype       : 'text' },
                   { name: 'EnquiryCreatedDate', width: 100, index: 'EnquiryCreatedDate',
                         searchoptions: {
                             sopt: ['eq','ge', 'le'],sorttype: 'date',
                             dataInit: function (element) {
                                 $(element).datepicker({
                                     id: 'ActionDate_datePicker',
                                     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                                     //minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
                                   //  maxDate: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
                                     showOn: 'focus'
                                 });
                             }
                         }, searchrules: { "required": true }
                   },
                   { name: 'AssignedDate', index: 'AssignedDate', width: 100,
                         searchoptions: {
                             sopt: ['eq', 'ge', 'le'], sorttype: 'date',
                             dataInit: function (element) {
                                 $(element).datepicker({
                                     id: 'AssignedDate_datePicker',
                                     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                                     //minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
                                     //maxDate: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
                                     showOn: 'focus'
                                 });
                             }
                         }, width: 100, searchrules: { "required": true }
                   },
                   { name: 'EnquiryMode', index: 'EnquiryMode', width: 100, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, searchrules: { "required": true } },
                   { name: 'EnquiryReference', index: 'EnquiryReference', sorttype: 'text', width: 100, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, searchrules: { "required"      : true } },
                   { name: 'QuotesubmitedForApproval', index: 'QuotesubmitedForApproval', width: 200, sorttype: 'date',
                        searchoptions: {
                            sopt: ['ge', 'le'],  
                             dataInit: function (element) {
                                 $(element).datepicker({
                                     id: 'yetoappDate_datePicker',
                                     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',                                    
                                     showOn: 'focus'
                                 });
                             }
                         }, searchrules: { "required": true }
                   },
                   { name: 'Manager', index: 'Manager', width: 100, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, searchrules: { "required": true } },
                   { name: 'QuoteApprovedDate', index: 'QuoteApprovedDate', width: 100, sorttype: 'date',
                         searchoptions: {
                             sopt: ['ge', 'le'], 

                             dataInit: function (element) {
                                 $(element).datepicker({
                                     id: 'ApprovedDate_datePicker',
                                     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',                                
                                     showOn: 'focus'
                                 });
                             }
                         }, searchrules: { "required": true }
                   },
                   { name: 'QuoteSentDate', index: 'QuoteSentDate', width: 100, sorttype: 'date',
                         searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq','ge', 'le'] ,                           
                             dataInit: function (element) {
                                 $(element).datepicker({
                                     id: 'QuotesentDate_datePicker',
                                     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                                     //minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
                                    // maxDate: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
                                     showOn: 'focus'
                                 });
                             }
                         }, searchrules: { "required": true }
                   },
                   { name: 'QuoteValue', index: 'QuoteValue', sorttype: 'date', width: 100, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ge', 'le'] }, searchrules: {
                             "required": true,
                             "number": true

                         }
                         , sorttype: 'number'
                   },
                   { name: 'PurchaseOrderValue', index: 'PurchaseOrderValue', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ge', 'le'] }, width: 100,
                         searchrules: {
                           "required": true,
                           "number": true

                        }, sorttype: 'number'
                   },
                   { name: 'PurchaseOrderNo', index: 'PurchaseOrderNo', sorttype: 'date', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, width: 100, searchrules: { "required":     true } },
                   { name: 'PurchaseOrderDate', index: 'PurchaseOrderDate', sorttype: 'date', width: 100,
                     searchoptions: {
                         sopt: ['eq', 'ge', 'le'],  
                         dataInit: function (element) {
                            $(element).datepicker({
                              id: 'PODate_datePicker',
                              dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                              //minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
                              //maxDate: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
                              showOn: 'focus'
                            });
                         }    
                     }
                     ,searchrules: { "required": true }                  
                  },
                  { name: 'Reference', index: 'Reference', width: 100, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, searchrules: { "required": true } },
                  { name: 'PuchaseOrdertype', index: 'PuchaseOrdertype', sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }, searchrules: { "required": true }
                  },
                  { name: 'SalesOpportunity', index: 'SalesOpportunity', sorttype: 'text', stype: "select", width: 150, 
                         searchoptions: {
                             clearSearch: false,
                             value: "open:Open;Closed:Closed;Drop:Drop;Lost:Lost", sopt: ['eq'],
                             //buildSelect: createSelectList,
                             //attr: { multiple: 'multiple', size: 2 },
                             //dataInit: dataInitMultiselect,
                             //buildSelect: createSelectList
                         },
                     searchrules: { "required": true }
                 },
                ],
                //footerrow: true,
                //userDataOnFooter: true,
                rowNum: 50,
                rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
                shrinkToFit: false,               
                //sortable: false,
                autoencode: true,

                sortname: 'LastActionDate',
                sortorder: "Asc",
                multiselect: false,
                frozenColumns: false,
                ReorderCoulmns : true,              
                ignoreCase: true,
                pager: "#navGrid",
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: false,
                width: 1200,
                height: 500,              
                //rownumbers: true, // show row numbers
                rownumWidth: 25, // the width of the row numbers columns              
                //loadComplete: loadCompleteHandler1,
                ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
                    jQuery(this).jqGrid('viewGridRow', rowid);
                },
                //beforeRequest: function () //loads the jqgrids state from before save
                //{
                //    modifySearchingFilter.call(this, ',');
                //},
                sortable: {
                    update: function (perm) {
                        if (perm) {
                            $("#datagrid").jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true);
                            var colModels = $("#navGrid").getGridParam("colModel");
                        }
                    }
                },
                caption: 'MIS Report',
                loadError: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var errorMsg = xhr.responseText;
                    var msg = "Some errors occurred during processing:";
                    msg += '\n\n' + textStatus + '\n\n' + errorMsg;
                    //g.trackError(msg, document.URL, 0);
                }



    });   
    $('#datagrid').navGrid("#navGrid", {
        search: true, // show search button on the toolbar
        add: false,
        edit: false,
        del: false,
        refresh: true,
        position: "left", cloneToTop: true
       },
       {}, // edit options
       {}, // add options
       {}, // delete options
       {
           closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true, overlay: false,
           closeAfterSearch: true 
       } // search options - define multiple search
    );
    $.extend(true, $.ui.multiselect, {
        locale: {
            addAll: 'Make all visible',
            removeAll: 'Hidde All',
            itemsCount: 'Avlialble Columns'
        }
    });

    $('#datagrid').jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#navGrid', {
                caption: "",
                buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
                title: "Choose columns",
                onClickButton: function () {
                    debugger
                    $("#datagrid").jqGrid('columnChooser',
                        {
                            width: 550, msel_opts: { dividerLocation: 0.5 }, modal: true,
                            done: function (perm) {
                                debugger
                                if (perm) {
                                    // "OK" button are clicked
                                    $("#datagrid").jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true);
                                    // the grid width is probably changed co we can get new width
                                    // and adjust the width of other elements on the page
                                //    var gwdth = $("#datagrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "width");
                                //    $("#datagrid").jqGrid("setGridWidth", 1200);
                                //} else {
                                //    // we can do some action in case of "Cancel" button clicked
                                }
                            }
                        });


                }

            });


            $('#datagrid').navButtonAdd('#navGrid', {

                caption: "Export",
                buttonicon: "ui-icon-disk",
                onClickButton:

                    function () {
                        debugger
                        var d = new Date();

                        var filename = "MISExport_" + d.getDate() + '/' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getFullYear().toString() + ".xlsx";
                        //jQuery("#datagrid").jqGrid('jqGridExport', options);
                        ExportJQGridDataToExcel("#datagrid", filename);

                    },

                position: "last"
            });

            $("#datagrid").jqGrid("setFrozenColumns");

        });
```

Comment: check if you have any console errors in browser??

Comment: i have fixed my error. error was reference to the script files was wrong. now working fine